# SVD did not converge when initializing LSTM weights (keras) in a for loop that contains savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, lstm

What I am trying to do:
Train multiple LSTM networks using a for loop.

This is the code to reproduce the error:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

#  LSTM
save_folder = r'C:'

for i in range(2):
    input_dim = (5, 6)
    input = Input(input_dim)
    output_dim = 1

    lstm = LSTM(25, return_sequences=True)(input)

    output = Dense(output_dim, activation='linear')(lstm)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
    model.summary()

    #  In my full code I train the model and compute results here

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.hist(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_folder, 'Figure.png'))
    plt.close(fig)
```

I get an error when going into the for loop for the second time

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jeroe/PycharmProjects/HUG/setup_LSTM_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    lstm = LSTM(25, return_sequences=True)(input)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 541, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 502, in build
    self.cell.build(step_input_shape)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 1925, in build
    constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 279, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape, dtype=dtype),
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 268, in __call__
    u, _, v = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1612, in svd
    u, s, vh = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 106, in _raise_linalgerror_svd_nonconvergence
    raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

When removing the line

```
plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_folder, 'Figure.png'))
```

The code runs as expected and prints the model summary twice

I tried adding a plt.pause(0.5) after the savefig command but that did not help. What kind of voodoo is going on here?

Comment: try defining figure outside of loop only once

Comment: Saving the figure outside the for loop is indeed the workaround I have implemented right now. However, I create 12 figures in each iteration so this quickly leads to having a lot of figures open which is not ideal (matplotlib is already warning me that there are more than 20 figures open). Are there any others ways to save a figure?

Btw, I have another function in the for loop that saves a figure which does not lead to problems with initialization of the weight in the next iteration. so the plot thickens.

Comment: I meant not saving outside of loop but "creating" the `figure` variable outside of loop
and destroying it only after loop exit